# Adding comments to a project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-project-file

There is a "comment" tag foreseen in Eclipse .project files but, despite (several years using Eclipse,) heavy googling and searches in the Eclipse Help, I haven't been able to find a way to specify, display and/or edit this field (besides directly editing the .project file).  (No, "Project -> Properties" doesn't seem to offer any solution)

I would like to use it to link a description to my (now fairly numerous) Eclipse projects in a project inventory tool.  (Being able to display/edit them in an Eclipse window would be nice, too).

Thanks for any hint on this question (and sorry if it appears to be a trivial one).

Kind regards

Comment: +1 I can easily set the comment for the project, controlling all my projects with Gradle by build.gradle file - I can set there virtually everything. But what is the use of the comment, if I don't see it anywhere?

Comment: I have the same perspective ... and questions. Would like to be able to view those when hovering over projects.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the Eclipse source there does not appear to be any way to set the .project comment field other than actually editing the .project file.

Eclipse will maintain any comment that is set this way but doesn't display the comment anywhere.